# Xcode 6.1.1 Swift returns "Optional("$1234.12")" with formatter

Tags: xcode, swift, formatting, currency

i'm just in playground trying to get this thing to work, but it doesn't want to work for me..

```
var total = 1234.1234
var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
println("\(formatter.stringFromNumber(total))")
// Returns: "Optional("$1,234.12")" instead of just "$1,234.12"
```

I want to show just the formatted number to the user but the extra Optional bit keeps showing up.

Comment: Please read the NSNumberFormatter documentation. The return value of `stringFromNumber()` is `String?`. Then read the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) to understand what the question mark means, and what an Optional is ...

Comment: As to why this is optional: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103113/does-nsnumberformatter-stringfromnumber-ever-return-nil

Comment: No idea why this question was downvoted into negative. Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just in playgrounds and are sure that the optional contains a value,
you can use forced unwrappping by adding an exclamation mark:

```
print("\(formatter.stringFromNumber(total)!)")
```