# Does NSNumberFormatter.stringFromNumber ever return nil?

Tags: swift, null, nsnumber, option-type, nsnumberformatter

It seems to me that any valid number can also be expressed as a `String`, so I don't know why this function returns a `String?` instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess would be because of the legacy support. This is from the official documentation:

> The behavior of an NSNumberFormatter object can conform either to the range of behaviors existing prior to OS X v10.4 or to the range of behavior since that release.
>   [NSNumberFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/)