# Why does NumberFormatter's string(from:) return an optional?

Tags: ios, swift

[Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1418046-string)

Why does the `NumberFormatter` function `func string(from number: NSNumber) -> String?` return a `String?` rather than a `String`? Are there particular inputs or states for a `NumberFormatter` where this function could return nil? Sometimes I hear these less-than-ideal return types are from Objective-C holdover files, is this one of those cases?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103113/does-nsnumberformatter-stringfromnumber-ever-return-nil

Comment: @vadian thanks. I guess, in practicality, I'm here to ask if I can in good conscience force unwrap these statements whenever I want, and that post leans me towards "yes".

Comment: @vadian: Actually that is the identical question. (The answer is not completely satisfying though.)

Comment: @MartinR That's why I didn't mark it as duplicate 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an ancient (2002) response on the [Apple mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2002/Dec/msg00370.html) which might partially answer your question:

> The strange behavior isn't NSNumber -- NSNumber -stringValue seems to be returning results one would expect. It's NSNumberFormatter which is returning unusual results.
>
> The abstract problem here is that NSNumberFormatter was originally written to handle money amounts for EOF, so it doesn't deal with unusual numbers well (or general purpose string formatting for that matter).
>
> The more concrete problem is that when you ask an NSNumberFormatter for -stringForObjectValue:, if the object is not an NSDecimalNumber, it converts it to an NSDecimalNumber using
> [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[objectValue stringValue]]
> which is not going to handle unusual values well, in addition to potentially other issues. A further issue, though I don't know this is the case, is that I don't think there is an NSDecimal (the struct) representation of positive and negative infinity, as there is for NaN.

I don't actually understand that response enough to say that it's why an optional is returned, but I suspect it's related.

There's example code in the original question, but none of it returns a `nil`, it always gives a string.

Comment: The most relevant portion seems to be "when you ask an NSNumberFormatter for -stringForObjectValue:, if the object is not an NSDecimalNumber, it converts it to an NSDecimalNumber using [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[objectValue stringValue]] which is not going to handle unusual values well". Makes it sound like there's an implementation detail in there that could lead to null values in Obj-C use cases but not Swift.

Comment: Thanks for digging this up! It's more of an answer than I was expecting.

Comment: Cheers, it's an interesting question. Maybe some of Apple engineers had an argument about whether NaN should be nil or not and they compromised with an optional. ‍♂️

Answer (score 14):

*Just for fun:* Here is a (constructed, not real-world) example where
`string(from:)` actually returns `nil`:

```
let num = NSNumber(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: 1)!, objCType: "v")
print(num) // <>

let fmt = NumberFormatter()
fmt.numberStyle = .decimal
let str = fmt.string(from: num)

print(str as Any) // nil
```

The reason is that this `num` does not represent a number: It is created
using the `NSValue` (from which its inherits) initializer
[`init(bytes:objCType:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue/1411621-init) with a value representing `void`. ("v" is the [type encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) for `void`,
the pointer value is irrelevant.)

Comment: How do you know all this?! nice :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fair to say that if you try to format a common type (like `Double`) to `String` using a `NumberFormatter`, there is no way it would return `nil`.

In my opinion, this is one of the few cases where force-unwrapped optionals make perfect sense.

```
func formatToDecimalNumber(_ value: Double) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))!
}
```

Comment: Maybe to be extra safe you could add `?? "\(value)"` to the return. Depending on how important that formatting is in your app.